# Google Webfont issue on dropbox

Tags: fonts, dropbox

i uploaded a website to my public folder on dropbox with two different fonts (open sans and caveat) from google.

Locally all looks fine, but while accessing the site with the public link one font (caveat) just doesn‘t show up.

Both fonts are linked exactly the same. 
Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are requesting the fonts via `http` instead of `https`. If you look in your browser dev tools you will see the error

[image]

Change your request to `https` and it will work fine. e.g.

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600`